# Is it possible to use {} as delimiter for an optional xparse argument?

Tags: xparse

I'm redefining beamer blocks to use tcolorboxes.

I want to make the title optional, but want to keep the curly braces.

How can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{d{}}{Hello\IfValueT{#1}{~#1}!}

\begin{document}
  \test
  \test{Bernd}
\end{document}
```

And this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{d\{\}}{Hello\IfValueT{#1}{~#1}!}

\begin{document}
  \test
  \test{Bernd}
\end{document}
```

Both do not work, the first raises an error (use a single token as delimiter) the second one simply ignores the argument.

Comment: There's a good reason that LaTeX sticks to one syntax for optional arguments: as noted in the answer, grabbing using a brace group is doable but that's not the same as recommended!

Comment: I'm writing a wrapper around existing code,  not designing my own.  I fully agree with you that the delimiters should show the kind of the argument

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it was here for the general reader: we added it as of course there are places it makes sense, particularly if the syntax is already fixed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read the `xparse` manual more carefully, hint: the `g` specifier

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\test{ g }{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{Test}{#1}
}
\begin{document}

\test

\test{Hmm}

\end{document}
```