# How to use xparse's NewDocumentCommand for global definition?

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

This is re: egreg's solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470137/how-to-call-command-with-optional-arg-using-instead-of/470146?noredirect=1#comment1184596_470146).

## Issue:

I would like the `\NameOne` command to replicate the `\NameTwo` command where it outputs only when being called on like so: `\NameOne`. When an argument is being entered into the command: `\NameOne{}` or `\Name{Argument}` it prints nothing and is only defining a global definition (as done in `\NameTwo`).

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NameOne}{g}
 {
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
   {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_jalep_nameone_tl {#1}
   }
  \tl_use:N \g_jalep_nameone_tl 
 }
\tl_new:N \g_jalep_nameone_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\NameTwo}[1]{\xdef\NameTwo{#1}}

\begin{document}
\textbf{NameOne}
\par This should say nothing: \NameOne{Argument}
\par This should say Argument: \NameOne
\par \hrulefill
\par \textbf{NameTwo}
\par This should say nothing: \NameTwo{Argument}
\par This should say Argument: \NameTwo
\end{document}
```

## Output:

[image]

## Edit:

I realize my question has been previously answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255762/is-it-possible-to-use-as-delimiter-for-an-optional-xparse-argument). If a moderator thinks this question is a repeat, feel free to mark it as such.

Comment: you should think really hard before using `g` option in any distributed code, it breaks all latex syntax guidelines. It is useful in some very special circumstances but should not be used for general latex document commands.

Comment: Did you try `\NameTwo{élite}`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will be careful about using this `g` option. I'm doing all of this for my own curiosity and to better understand the TeX -> LyX relationship, but all in experimentation. @egreg I'm not quite sure I understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use both possible branches of `\IfNoValue` (namely `\IfNoValueTF`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NameOne}{g}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {
        \tl_use:N \g_jalep_nameone_tl 
      }
      {
        \tl_gset:Nn \g_jalep_nameone_tl {#1}
      }
  }
\tl_new:N \g_jalep_nameone_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\NameTwo}[1]{\xdef\NameTwo{#1}}

\begin{document}
\textbf{NameOne}
\par This should say nothing: \NameOne{Argument}
\par This should say Argument: \NameOne
\par \hrulefill
\par \textbf{NameTwo}
\par This should say nothing: \NameTwo{Argument}
\par This should say Argument: \NameTwo
\end{document}
```

[image]